# Installation fails on VirtualBox (bad checksum) while on Hyper-V works fine

Tags: virtualbox, centos, hyper-v

I am trying to install CentOs using this iso `CentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-minimal.iso` on VirtualBox 6.1.

Installation fails during media check, please see the error below.
On Hyper-V the same iso file was used, and installation was OK, there was not any checksum errors, system was installed and is working fine. 
What can be reason of this error ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a thread where the issue is discussed and resolved:

[Centos Installation Fails with CD Check Failed on all ISOs](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97391)

TLDR: CentOS installation fails when used under VirtualBox on a host where Hyper-V is enabled. You'll have to either disable Hyper-V or install it differently.

Comment: Good answer.  I didn't even read the question correctly. !bliat! As a note to your answer, ***I myself have enabled hyper-v on or off at boot using bcdedit.  People can find how to do that online***.  1 more point for you!